# How to define, raise and handle async events in ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, events, delegates

I want to use `delegate` for my async events. But whole topic seems difficult to me.

I don't know how to register events and how to register handlers that has the same logic for all raises. By this I mean that I want to have async event handler with always the same logic that is always invoked when appropriate event is invoked.

From what I've seen I would have to use a static class for handler like this. But I can't use static class, because my handler need to use some dependencies.

My understanding of this looks like:[image]

I really don't understand how to use async events and generally how to properly define, use and handle events. Please explain it and give me easy example. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a  look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/implementing-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern).

Comment: @QingGuo But what about async Task, not void?

Comment: I'm not sure a delegate is the right approach -- they seem to be used less and less.  Some alternatives would be Reactive Extensions (https://levelup.gitconnected.com/introduction-to-rx-net-87e4a6c6e71b) or a library like MediatR (https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR).

Comment: But it seems that delegates are only way to do `async Task` instead of `async void`. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think you would best be served by using Mediatr. It has async event handling and will also let you inject in the dependencies that you need: https://medium.com/@mohsen_rajabi/how-in-mediatr-we-can-have-events-notifications-async-and-completely-real-parallel-2068f24912e6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Async

When working with `async` methods, you usually return a `Task` to the caller to wait for.

```cs
async Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
    // async will implicitly create a new task and return it.
    return;
}

var task = MyAsyncMethod();

// execute the task
await task;

// the task is done
```

If you don't, the `async` keyword will execute the method because it can't create a task.

```cs
async void MyAsyncMethod()
{
    return;
}

// the method execution is started, because it's async
MyAsyncMethod();
```

### Events

Usually, the event source (`MyAppEvents`) only cares about raising events, it doesn't know how many listeners there are, so it can't excepted them a return value.

To define an event, you need 2 things

- the event handlers signature
- the event definition (its name basically)

```cs
// event handlers signature
public delegate SomeReturnValueType MyEventDelegate(FirstArgType arg1);

// event definition
public event MyEventDelegate MyEventName;
```

You could think that you could use `SomeReturnValueType` to return values from the handlers, but if you do so

```cs
var result = MyEventName.Invoke();
```

`result` would be set to the last handler's return value.

### Mixing both

If you define your handlers to return a `Task` and try to `await` them when raising the event, you'll only await the last handler's task.

```cs
// task only represents the last handler
var task = MyAsyncEvent.Invoke();

await task;
```

Doing this may lead to confusion, so I'd recommand to define the handlers delegate to **not** return a `Task`, so nobody is attempted to `await`.

```cs
public delegate void MyAsyncMethod();
```

When raising an event, the execution will continue as the event source doesn't (and shouldn't) know about the handlers.

### Workaround

Making use of dependency injection, you could define services as your event handlers.

```cs
public interface IEventHandler<in TEvent>
{
     Task ExecuteAsync(TEvent @event);
}

// custom handler
public class CustomEventHandler : IEventHandler<CustomEvent>
{
     public Task ExecuteAsync(CustomEvent @event)
     {
          // do logic
     }
}

// the event source
public class MyAppEvents
{
     private readonly IEnumerable<IEventHandler<CustomEvent>> _handlers;
    
     public MyAppEvents(IEnumerable<IEventHandler<CustomEvent>> handlers)
     {
          _handlers = handlers;
     }

     private async Task RaiseCustomEventAsync()
     {
        var @event = new CustomEvent();
        
        var tasks = _handlers.Select(h => t.Execute(@event));

        // execute all task and await them
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
     }
}
```

Comment: If it's async void there is problem with exceptions. And I cant be sure that event was properly handled. I thought events are more nice to use.

Comment: @Szyszka947 you could use services and DI instead.